# jupyter notebook crashes latex during conversion to pdf

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex, markdown

When I try to write a math function in jupyter notebook markdown cell, it gives it hundreds of lines of incomplete unreadable error messages during conversion to PDF using latex. If I remove this math function it works fine, even with other math functions. It seems like there's some weird interaction going on with latex attempting to read this. Would anyone be able to notice why?

```
$$
m_{M,n}(x;\Theta_{1},..,\Theta_{M},D_{n}) = \left\{
    \begin{array}\\
        1 & if \frac{1}{M} \sum \limits _{j=1} ^{M} m_{n}(x;\Theta_{j},D_{n}) > 1/2 \\
        0 & otherwise
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
```

[The output is supposed to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGy6X.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LaTeX code isn't valid. `array` environments expect an alignment argument to be passed, like `\begin{array}{ll}` for two columns left-aligned.

Also, the `\\` in the first line isn't necessary at all.

The working code would be:

```latex
$$
    m_{M,n}(x;\Theta_{1},..,\Theta_{M},D_{n}) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            1 & \mathrm{if}\; \frac{1}{M} \sum \limits _{j=1} ^{M}  m_{n}(x;\Theta_{j},D_{n}) > 1/2 \\
            0 & \mathrm{otherwise}
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$
```

[Result](http://www.texrendr.com/?eqn=m_%7BM%2Cn%7D(x%3B%5CTheta_%7B1%7D%2C..%2C%5CTheta_%7BM%7D%2CD_%7Bn%7D)%20%3D%20%5Cleft%5C%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Cbegin%7Barray%7D%7Bll%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201%20%26%20%5Cmathrm%7Bif%7D%5C%3B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7BM%7D%20%5Csum%20%5Climits%20_%7Bj%3D1%7D%20%5E%7BM%7D%20%20m_%7Bn%7D(x%3B%5CTheta_%7Bj%7D%2CD_%7Bn%7D)%20%3E%201%2F2%20%5C%5C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200%20%26%20%5Cmathrm%7Botherwise%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Cend%7Barray%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%5Cright.):

[image: Result]

### But why does it work in Jupyter Notebook?

It's because Jupyter Notebook uses MathJax, another TeX implementation, that uses `cc` by default when you don't inform the alignment of `array`. Therefore, Jupyter Notebook (or MathJax) really doesn't care if your code is missing that.

However, on the LaTeX side, the thing is quite different. In LaTeX, any parameter passed with `{}` is required (opposed to `[]`, which is optional), so when you write `\begin{array}\\`, TeX is trying to expand the `\\` token as an alignment argument, which obviously throws an error (first because `\\` isn't expected and then because you passed only one argument and is trying to use two columns).

Comment: This fixed my problem and helped me understand. Thank you so much.